# how to map Visual Studio 2013 arrow keys command to something else?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I would like to map the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys in Visual Studio 2013 to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

I can't find a command that does it in the environment/keyboard.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Do you want to use Emacs-like bindings in VS?

Comment: well, i guess yes but i dont want to install anything so things sync across machines just using my login.